# How can I count total number of user registered with their respective roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, roles

I have a buying and selling rails app, where users have two roles buyers and sellers i want to show records on my homepage that how many buyers are there on the site and how many sellers on the site.
but by using the `User.count` it shows all the user registered on my site

**My seeds.rb**

```
['buyer', 'seller'].each do |role|
  Role.find_or_create_by({name: role})
end
```

*Models*

**Role.rb**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

**Users.rb**

```
   belongs_to :role
   def has_role? test_role
       role.id == 2
       role.id == 1
   end
```

Comment: How are roles related to the user?  What kind of associations have you defined on the models?

Comment: please have a look now added models @infused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a role object to count by role:

```
role = Role.find_by(name: 'buyer')
User.where(role: role).count
```

Or you can include the roles table and query through users:

```
User.includes(:role).where(role: {name: 'buyer'}).count
```